# Edit profile page redirect to desktop theme

Tags: theming, javascript

I have two themes in my Drupal website, one for desktop resolution and second one for mobile(iPhone) resolution. When I browse website on mobile, all pages working fine except edit profile page.

Edit profile page in Mobile renders same as Desktop resolution theme.

I already have user-profile.tpl.php in mobile theme folder.

Any suggestions on how to make Edit Profile page compatible with Mobile ?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using mobile tools, other module or custom code for theme switching?

Comment: we are using themekey module to switch theme